# Can we treat "gibberish english" as a language?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

I am wondering if we can treat "gibberish english" as "english". By that I mean can we replace "english" with "gibberish english" in any sentence without changing the meaning of a sentence in ways they mean something completely different?

Here's an example:

> "A fight fought the wing fight gasped fight the fight." George sang in
>   gibberish English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gibberish is a noun in it's own right, so I wouldn't use it as a qualifier for any other specific language.

I would say

```
garbled English
```

to give the sense that the words being used might be identified as English words, but the words are combined in a confused or nonsensical manner.